# SQL query with joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have problem with my SQL query.

I try to eject these queries and the result is nothing.

```
$query =$db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('name'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__restaurant'));
$query->where($db->quote(constant("$vector[0]")) . '=' . $db->quote($v[$vector[0]]));
$db->setQuery($query);
$column=$db->loadObjectList();
```

.......

```
$query= $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('name'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__restaurant'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('zone'). '=' . $db->quoteName('atocha'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$column=$db->loadObjectList();
```

The database is not empty, but I why there is no results.
Any idea!!!

thanks

Thanks everyone I execute this

```
$query= "SELECT *
FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__restaurantes')."
WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('tipe')."=".$db->quote($v[$vector[0]]).";";
$db->setQuery($query);
$column=$db->loadObjectList();
```

and obtain this

SELECT * FROM `#__restaurantes` WHERE tipe='';sol

any idea

thanks

Comment: have you added `$db =& JFactory::getDBO();` to connect to the database? and have you used a foreach command after to display the results?

Comment: What happens when you write the query out?  What are you using to display the query?

Comment: yes I have $db = JFactory::getDBO(); and when I write count($column); I take 0,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks you so much everyone !

I have the correct query, I put here for some one who has the same problem.

```
$db=& JFactory::getDBO();

$query= "SELECT *
FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__restaurant')."
WHERE ".$db->nameQuote(constant("$vector[0]"))."=".$db->quote($v[$vector[0]]).";";
$db->setQuery($query);
$column=$db->loadObjectList();

return $column;
```

Comment: You really should be using Joomla's database abstraction layer as @soren-beck-jensen suggestes, see http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going a little owerboard with your quote() and quoteName() functions.

Try this:

```
$query= $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('name');
$query->from('#__restaurant');
$query->where('zone = "atocha"');
$db->setQuery($query);
$column = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Also, please post the resulting SQL if this does not work. You can get it by:

```
echo $db->getQuery();
```